# Filter (subset) by conditions in 2 columns in R (dplyr or otherwise)

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Given a dataset such as:

```
set.seed(134)
df<- data.frame(ID= rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=2),
           condition=rep(0:1, 5),
           value=rpois(10, 3)
           )
df

       ID condition value
1   A         0     2
2   A         1     3
3   B         0     5
4   B         1     2
5   C         0     3
6   C         1     1
7   D         0     2
8   D         1     4
9   E         0     1
10  E         1     5
```

For each ID, when the value for condition==0 is less than the value for condition==1, I want to keep both observations. When the value for condition==0 is greater than condition==1, I want to keep only the row for condition==0.

The subset returned should be this:

```
 ID condition value
1   A         0     2
2   A         1     3
3   B         0     5
5   C         0     3
7   D         0     2
8   D         1     4
9   E         0     1
10  E         1     5
```

Using dplyr the first step is:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
```

But not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating fairly literally,

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(134)

df <- data.frame(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 2),
                 condition = rep(0:1, 5),
                 value = rpois(10, 3))

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    filter(condition == 0 | 
               (condition == 1 & value > value[condition == 0]))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups: ID [5]
#>   ID    condition value
#>   <fct>     <int> <int>
#> 1 A             0     2
#> 2 A             1     3
#> 3 B             0     5
#> 4 C             0     3
#> 5 D             0     2
#> 6 D             1     4
#> 7 E             0     1
#> 8 E             1     5
```

This depends on each group having a single observation with `condition == 0`, but should otherwise be fairly robust.

Comment: Thank you - this is the simplest and most robust solution...  in particular, the ability to have "sub-conditions"  ...`| (condition == 1 & value > value[condition == 0])` is the part I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

This is may not be the easiest way, but should work as you want.

```
library(reshape2)
df %>% 
    dcast(ID ~ condition, value.var = 'value') %>% # cast to wide format
    mutate(`1` = ifelse(`1` > `0`, `1`, NA)) %>% # turn 0>1 values as NA
    melt('ID') %>% # melt as long format
    arrange(ID) %>% # sort by ID
    filter(complete.cases(.)) # remove NA rows
```

Output:

```
ID variable value
1  A        0     2
2  A        1     3
3  B        0     5
4  C        0     3
5  D        0     2
6  D        1     4
7  E        0     1
8  E        1     5
```

Comment: Thanks. This works and I had thought about reshaping the data to solve the problem, but was hoping for something more direct & efficient, as @alistaire provided.

Answer (score 1):

You always want the value from the first row in each group. You only want the value from the second row in each group if it's larger than the first.

This works:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1 | value > lag(value))
```

Edit: as @alistaire points out, this method depends on a particular order in, which is might be a good idea to guarantee as follows:

```r
df %>% 
  arrange(ID, condition) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1 | value > lag(value))
```

Comment: The `lag` usage depends on a row order that hasn't been explicitly set. With `arrange` beforehand, this might be ok.

Comment: @ngm Thanks.  I should have provided a more realistic example dataset, because this solution is too specific to be applied to my real data (which has >2 conditions some of which can occur >1 time per ID)